# finding the 2 oldest kid from the list

Tags: python, dictionary

heres the problem

I have 3 student,
student A, John is 19 y/o,
student B, Mark is 16 y/o,
student C, Cindy is 17 y/0,

I want to write some code that show the 2 oldest among them, ie John, Cindy

so far I can get the age sort, but how do i get the name
(this is my 2nd week learning python so I think this should be simple to many but i just cant get it)

```
student1 = {"name" : "John",  "age" : 19}
student2 = {"name" : "Mark", "age" : 16}
student3 = {"name" : "Cindy", "age" : 17}

student_age = [student1["age"],student2["age"], student3["age"]]
student_age = sorted(student_age)
print (student_age[1:3])
```

Comment: you have to loop the `student_age` list, either using a `for` loop or with a generator expression. (the latter is a bit hard to grasp for people new to python)

Answer (score 2):

Sort the list of dictionaries by age in descending order using the [sorted] function[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), and get the first two values.

The sorted function is sorting in reverse order `reverse=True`, and is sorting on key age `key=lambda x:x['age']`

```
students = [{"name" : "John",  "age" : 19},
 {"name" : "Mark", "age" : 16},
 {"name" : "Cindy", "age" : 17}]


#Sort the elements by key age, in descending order
res = sorted(students, key=lambda x:x['age'], reverse=True)

#Get the first two elements of list
print(res[:2])
#[{'name': 'John', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Cindy', 'age': 17}]

#Get the name and age of top two students
for item in res[:2]:
    print(item['name'], item['age'])
John 19
Cindy 17
```

Comment: For learning sake, @lee, you can also use `res[:-3:-1]`. And if you just want the names `print([i["name"] for i in res[:-3:-1]])`

Comment: Glad to be of help sir @lee Please consider accepting my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

@DeveshKumarSingh's answer is correct, but you don't need to sort the list to get the two max values. The sort has an O(n lg n) time complexity, whereas the code below is a variation on `max` and has a O(n) time complexity.

```
>>> students = [
...    {"name": "John",  "age": 19},
...    {"name": "Mark", "age": 16},
...    {"name": "Cindy", "age": 17},
...    {"name": "Jim", "age": 18},
...    {"name": "Mary", "age": 15},
...    {"name": "Josy", "age": 21},
... ]
```

First, take the two first students and order them by descending age:

```
>>> fst, snd = students[:2]
>>> if fst['age'] < snd['age']: fst, snd = snd, fst
```

Them, loop over the remaining students, and update the older student and the second older student if necessary:

```
>>> for s in students[2:]:
...     if s['age'] > fst['age']: fst, snd = s, fst
...     elif s['age'] > snd['age']: snd = s
```

Here's the result:

```
>>> fst, snd
({'name': 'Josy', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 19})
```

For the record, this algorithm can be generalized to the `k` max elements with a priority queue.

Create a [`heap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) with the `k` first students:

```
>>> k = 3
>>> heap = [(s['age'], s) for s in students[:3]]
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.heapify(heap)
```

For each student, add the student in the heap and remove the youngest student of the heap. The heap always contain the `k` older students:

```
>>> for s in students[k:]:
...     heapq.heappushpop(heap, (s['age'], s))
>>> [h[1] for h in sorted(heap, reverse=True)]
[{'name': 'Josy', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Jim', 'age': 18}]
```

You don't event need to write this code, since the module `heapq` offers the function `nlargest`:

```
>>> [h[1] for h in heapq.nlargest(k, [(s['age'], s) for s in students])]
[{'name': 'Josy', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Jim', 'age': 18}]
```

The doc states:

> (`nlargest`) perform(s) best for smaller values of n. For larger values, it is more efficient to use the sorted() function.

Indeed, the time complexity is O(n lg k) and could be reduced with a comparison against the min of the `heap` before pushing the value on the heap (and a shuffle of the list of students to ensure that the `k` older students are uniformly distributed).